# How to display pixel arrays in GPU global memory onto screen directly?

Tags: opengl, cuda, gpu

I'm doing a path tracer on GPU, and I got some traced results of pixel data (which is an array of float3) on GPU global memory, what I do to display the array on screen is to copy the array to CPU memory and call OpenGL `glTexImage2D`:

```
glTexImage2D (GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelArray);
```

then display the texture. `pixelArray` is the pixel data array to show. As GPU is the device managing the whole rendering process, is there a way to display the `pixelArray` on screen without copying data from GPU to CPU?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "color pixel array"? Are you talking about an OpenGL buffer object that stores pixel data, a piece of CUDA memory that stores pixel data, or what?

Comment: that would be just an array of float3 (RGBcolor) type, which stored in GPU global memory. @NicolBolas

Comment: Right, but you tagged this as both OpenGL and CUDA. Each of them have their own, *separate* ways of storing an array of data in GPU global memory. And which way you used will impact the options you have for sticking this into a texture. So which is it?

Comment: we can forget about OpenGL. Pixel data do exist in cuda global memory like [(R,G,B),(R,G,B),...,(R,G,B)], to put array like this onto screen directly without CPU involved would reduce overhead. @NicolBolas

Comment: @Tony: No we can't forget about OpenGL. CUDA has graphics and OpenGL interop. You can map a OpenGL texture as CUDA global memory array. Either you write your data directly to a mapped texture, or you do a cudaMemcpy2D into the texture mapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use CUDA OpenGL graphics interop to map a OpenGL texture as CUDA global memory. Either write your data directly to the texture or use a cudaMemcpy2D.

Answer (score 1):

[Here is a function](http://pastebin.com/SYwhB4i4) I made once, to render the image whose data resides in the global memory of GPU.
You will require [`freeglut`](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) and [`glew`](http://glew.sourceforge.net/), alongwith CUDA to run it. Currently it works only on Windows.

I still use this function to render GPU images. Just call `ShowRawImage` and you are done.

The only overhead it has, is a memory copy from global memory to OpenGL device buffer. But its better because its a device to device copy.